# Angular 5 ngFor not working on datatables.net

Tags: datatables, angular5

Below is the screen shot the error when i want to display the data in the datatables using ngFor:

[Datatable output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q71Wx.png)

```
 This code for Angular html component. I try to insert data into the datatables from typescript. Currently i get the data trough api and i want to insert the data into the datatable by using ngFor but it not working as in image attach.

  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let company of companies">
       <td></td>
       <td>System Architect</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2011/04/25</td>
       <td>$320,800</td>
       <td>Malaysia</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
```

datatables.component.ts file:

```
companies: Company[];
constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {
this.companyService.getCompanies()
   .subscribe(
    (company: Company[]) => this.companies = company,
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done get company')
  );
}
```

Comment: your datasource is not properly binded please go through [angluar datatables](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and implement

Answer (score 3):

After some time searching for it, I found some steps that can help you with your angular problem.

First, you need to bind your data.

```
<table id="datatables">
    <thead>
        (...)
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        (...)
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let company of companies">
            <td>company.id</td>
            <td>company.systemArchitect</td>
            <td>company.place</td>
            <td>company.number</td>
            <td>company.date</td>
            <td>company.value</td>
            <td>company.country</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Second, in your .component.ts file, you'll need to do somethings a bit more complex.

You have done right your companyService.getCompanies, but to work with datatables.net it's necessary to call for dataTable(). But you need to wait for the data to arrive before you use.

One way, is using changeDetector of angular core. It can be used to trigger the detection of changes before the instaciation of the datatable.

Example:

```
companies: Company[];
constructor(private companyService: CompanyService, private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.companyService.getCompanies()
       .subscribe((company: Company[]) => {
          this.companies = company;

          // You'll have to wait that changeDetection occurs and projects data into 
          // the HTML template, you can ask Angular to that for you ;-)
          this.chRef.detectChanges();

          // Now you can use jQuery DataTables :
          const table: any = $('datatables');
          this.dataTable = table.DataTable();
       });
}
```

ref: https://medium.com/apprendre-le-web-avec-lior/angular-5-and-jquery-datatables-fd1dd2d81d99

Answer (score 0):

You can try bind these datas by {{company.object}}